# How do I develop my first web part?

Tags: 2007, development

I am a newbie in SharePoint development and I have an Oracle and ASP.NET background. Can you please guide me to any tutorial which can take me from building Web parts to showing them on a SharePoint site.

I am using VS 2008 and SQLServer 2008 with MOSS 2007.

Answer (score 2):

Straight from SharePoint developer center on MSDN with virtual labs and all

[Module 1: Getting Started Building Web Parts in SharePoint 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/ee513148.aspx)

Also a walkthrough on MSDN: [Walkthrough: Creating a Basic Web Part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms415817.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

An end to end implementation

http://www.datasprings.com/Resources/ArticlesInformation/Sharepoint2007CustomWebParts.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I would also suggest having a look at the following books by Tedd Pattison which will help get you started:

[Inside WSS 3.0](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735623201)

[Inside MOSS 2007](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735623686)

Answer (score 0):

Probably one of the most usefull tools in Sharepoint development (especially in WSS3.0 and MOSS2007) is [WSPBuilder](http://wspbuilder.codeplex.com/)
Be sure to install it on your machine as developing webparts and features is much easier with this plugin.